# I am using editor in react js , but after edit button click its showing "Loading failed! Please reload."

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and have editorwrapper used for other modules its working fine
but for one module after edit button click its showing "Loading failed! Please reload."

expected is on edit button click it show pop up the form that is to be edited

here is the code :

```
<Form.Item
            name="description"
            label="Description"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please Enter Description" }, {max:5000}]}
          >
            <EditorWrapper >
              <ReactQuill
                onChange={onEditorStateChange}
                ref={reactQuillRef}
                value={editorContent}
                placeholder="Assessment Description"
                readOnly={article.newJobOpeningAdd === commonConstant.isView ? true : false}
              /></EditorWrapper>
          </Form.Item>


    const handleModal = (article = null, isView = null) => {
        setErrorMessage('');
        if (article !== null) {
          article.newJobOpeningAdd = commonConstant.isDefaultOne;  // added vale in array
          let year = 0;
          let month = 0;
          let experienceArray = [];
          if (article.experience !== undefined && article.experience !== null) {
            experienceArray = article.experience.split(',');
          }
    
          if (experienceArray.length > 1) {
            year = experienceArray[0];
            month = experienceArray[1];
          }
    
          var job_arr = {
            expired_date: article.expired_date ? moment(article.expired_date) : '',
            category_name: article.skill_info.skill_sub_category_info.skill_category_info.name,
            sub_category_name: article.skill_info.skill_sub_category_info.name,
            skill_name: article.skill_info.name,
            skill_category_id: article.skill_info.skill_sub_category_info.skill_category_info.id,
            skill_sub_category_id: article.skill_info.skill_sub_category_info.id,
            skill_id: article.skill_info.id,
            org_name: article.organization_info.name,
            year: year,
            month: month
          } // Values are appended 
    
          setEditorContent(article.job_description);
          article = { ...article, ...job_arr }
          setInitialState(article); // Updated all value to InitialState
    
          let params = commonConstant.dropdownParams;
          params.organization_id = article.organization_info.id;
          params.skill_category_id = article.skill_category_id;
          params.skill_sub_category_id = article.skill_sub_category_id;
          params.skill_id = article.skill_id;
    
          callApi(api.skill_category, params);
          callApi(api.skill_sub_category, params);
          callApi(api.skill, params);
    
        }
    
        if (isView !== commonConstant.isNull) {
          article.newJobOpeningAdd = isView;
        }
    
        dispatch(toggleModal(article));
    
      };
```

also i tried `value={editorContent || ''}`  i got the expected result but its not the permanent solution .